# Is it possible to add an ethernet port to raspberry pi a+?

Tags: networking

I will receive a Raspberry pi model a+ tomorrow.

Does anyone tried to add an ethernet port to it?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution known to me, is an USB to Ethernet adapter.
Here is a list with Raspberry Pi compatible adapters: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Ethernet_adapters

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any reason a [USB to Ethernet dongle](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=usb+to+ethernet+dongle&_sop=15) woudn't work.  Have you considered using a wireless dongle instead?

I'd expect most people would use a USB hub so that several USB devices could be connected.

Answer (score 2):

You may need an external powered hub for it but it almost certainly supports most USB Ethernet adapters that any other linux machine does. The model B is just using an onboard USB hub and Ethernet adapter so it's really not all that different.